# Superclass method cannot find overridden method in subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, encapsulation

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Person().printPerson();
        new Student().printPerson();
    }
}

class Student extends Person
{
    public String getInfo()
    {
        return "Student";
    }
}

class Person
{
    private String getInfo()
    {
        return "Person";
    }

    public void printPerson()
    {
        System.out.println(getInfo());
    }
}
```

The output to this is:

```
Person
Person
```

Why is the second line not Student?  The parent `getInfo()` is private but does that mean that the second call of `printPerson()` is prevented from finding the child `getInfo()` (which is public)?  I think that the child method cannot inherit the private `getInfo()` so overriding does not occur.

Comment: That's another reason to always use `@Override` annotation.

Answer (score 3):

> The parent getInfo() is private but does that mean that the second call of printPerson() is prevented from finding the child getInfo() (which is public)?

Yes. The subclass's `getInfo()` method is not *overriding* the superclass's one, as it doesn't even logically *know* about it. Private methods can't be overridden.

From [section 8.4.8.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1):

> An instance method m1, declared in class C, overrides another instance method m2, declared in class A iff all of the following are true:
>
> - C is a subclass of A.
> - The signature of m1 is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of m2.
> - Either:
>
>   - m2 is public, protected, or declared with default access in the same package as C, or
>   - m1 overrides a method m3 (m3 distinct from m1, m3 distinct from m2), such that m3 overrides m2.

Note the first sub-bullet - in your case, `m2` is `Person.getInfo`, and that *isn't* public, protected or declared with default access in the same package - so that sub-bullet doesn't apply. The other sub-bullet doesn't apply either, so you're not meeting all the requirements for overriding.

You should use the `@Override` annotation when you're trying to override a method in a superclass - that way if you're doing something wrong, you'll get a compile-time error instead of just getting unexpected behaviour at execution time.

Comment: So let's say that m1 and m2 were both public, and m1 overrides m2 successfully.  As above, printPerson() is called by Student().  The output will be 

    'Person'
'Student'

Does it first look for some evidence of overriding inside of m2, the local method, before going to Student to use its getInfo()?

Comment: @user2782804: It's not clear what you mean. The details of how overriding is performed within the VM is an implementation detail - but the language clearly states that while it's private in the superclass, you're not overriding it in the subclass. Or were you interested in the differences in the bytecode?

Comment: I guess I'm just confused as to why, when the parent getInfo() is private and the child one public, printPerson() can not or does not find the child getInfo().  Even with the knowledge that overriding does NOT occur, it appears to be Student calling (an inherited?) printPerson(), and I assumed the program (upon calling printPerson()) would first search through the Student class for a getInfo() rather than the parent Person class.

Comment: @user2782804: It doesn't because the subclass can't possibly be *trying* to override the method - it doesn't "know" about it. It would be very dangerous if subclasses *could* override private methods - private methods are meant to be a hidden implementation detail... and one where the caller (in the same class) *knows* that the only implementation that can be called is the one they've declared.

Answer (score 0):

If the method is intended to be overridden by child class, that method should be visible to child class.

i.e. You should declare the `getInfo()` method as protected instead of private.

Comment: You completely missed the question.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I think you missed my answer instead.  `getInfo()` is declared private in super class.  Hence, the `getInfo()` in child is simply not overridding the parent one.  Hence, `getInfo()` invoked in `printPerson()` is simply not a "virtual" method (using C++ terminology), and hence, no vtable lookup, and hence, not invoking child class' `getInfo()`

Answer (score 0):

The `getInfo` method is not overridden by `Student` class, so when a call to printPerson goes to getInfo, it executes the local getInfo method.